# Signing .apk to BlackBerry App World

Tags: eclipse, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

I run my .apk file from eclipse to BlackBerry Playbook.  It runs successfully.  After that, when I sign my application for BlackBerry App World from Eclipse, it successfully signs it and gives me bar file in dist folder.  However that file is marked crossed which indicates that the bar file contains an error.  I don't know how to debug the error.  I have made 2 layouts: one layout for Playbook and the other for BlackBerry Alpha 10.  Is this causing an error or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This APK was already packaged and signed, please update the APK’s version number to package again
```

This error means you are signing the same build again, with the same version no. Blackberry signer identifies the debug build and release build both as same, as they have same version no. So to overcome this, just change the version no. of the release build. It'll work without any problem.